# How can I control the size of a CCScrollView?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ccscrollview

When using a CCScrollView I would like to be able to limit the viewable area to a certain bounding box. How can this be achieved?

Setting the content size does not affect the viewable area.

Comment: not possible within scrollview, perhaps combine it with a clipping node or draw a frame sprite over it

Comment: Would you be willing to take a look at the solution that I found? Would you consider that to be a reasonable way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found what seems to be a reasonable way to do this. There was some code on the cocos2d forum for clipping an area using `GL_SCISSOR`:

http://forum.cocos2d-swift.org/t/cocos2d-3-1-beta-gl-scissor-test/13608/4

```
-(void)visit:(CCRenderer *)renderer parentTransform:(const GLKMatrix4 *)parentTransform
{
    CGPoint positionInWorldCoords = [self convertToWorldSpace:ccp(0, 0)];
    CGFloat contentScaleFactor = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] contentScaleFactor];

    positionInWorldCoords = ccpMult(positionInWorldCoords, contentScaleFactor);


    [renderer enqueueBlock:^{
        glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
        glScissor(positionInWorldCoords.x, positionInWorldCoords.y, self.contentSize.width * contentScaleFactor, self.contentSize.height * contentScaleFactor);
} globalSortOrder:0 debugLabel:nil threadSafe:YES];

    [super visit:renderer parentTransform:parentTransform];

    [renderer enqueueBlock:^{
        glDisable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
    } globalSortOrder:0 debugLabel:nil threadSafe:YES];
}
```

So I subclassed `CCScrollView` and added this method. I ended up having to tweak the coordinates a bit to get the exact right clipping area. Seems like a clunky answer so I hope someone has a better answer.

Comment: yup, that's what the CCClippingNode does as well

Comment: Thanks! That seems like a much better mechanism. Do you want to add that as an answer so that I can mark that one as correct?